# Warning when using Apache Derby in memory

Tags: derby, in-memory

I have a number of unit tests, which use Apache Derby in memory.
My connection url is: `jdbc:derby:memory:srf.derby;create=true`

I discovered that each time, when a method marked as `@Transactional` is finishing, I receive a Derby warning

```
12:53:28:5328 [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] [main] WARN  - SQL Warning: 10000, SQLState: 01J01
12:53:28:5328 [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] [main] WARN  - Database 'memory:srf.derby' not created, connection made to existing database instead.
```

Why is it? What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Is it Spring's @Transactional?

Answer (score 10):

You're not doing anything wrong. You're passing ';create=true' each time, but the database is only created the first time your program accesses it. Since it's in-memory, the database then hangs around until your program exits, at which point it disappears.

You could avoid the warning by passing ';create=true' only on the first test in your test suite, and then subsequent tests do not need to pass that value.

Or, you could just not worry about the warning.

Comment: I see that the problem is not database creation. During the same test, each time I execute a transactional method this warning is printed.

I switched to a file based embedded DB, but still have the same warning

Comment: To be precise, each time you connect to a Derby database which already exists, using a connection URL that contains ";create=true", you will get the warning. It's not because it's in-memory, it's because it already exists and you are telling Derby to create it.